# Showing POST parameters in Rails ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, parameters, activeresource

I am using [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) to get and post resources from an external API.  Even though that in the logs I can see the calls that are being performed, I fail to see the params. Shouldn't the params hash be printed by default?

How/what should I add to be able to see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ActiveResource Post call syntax is:**

```
post(your_custom_method_name, options={}, body='')
```

Here *options is query parameter*

Ex:

```
Customer.post(:bulk_import, {}, { new_customers: new_customers}.to_json)
```